# What is the reason array is available inside reduce(), map(), etc.?

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, reduce

In the following example, we have access to the array as `numbers` and `arr`. It seems more in line with functional programming to use the internal variable `arr` but what is an explicit reason why we should use it instead of the exterior variable, since, `numbers` and `arr` are both pointers to the same array value anyway.

```
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const sum = numbers.reduce((acc, m, index, arr) => {
    console.log(`acc=${acc}, m=${m}, index=${index}, arr=${arr}`);
    console.log(`acc=${acc}, m=${m}, index=${index}, numbers=${numbers}`);
    return acc += m;
}, 100);
console.log(sum);
```

Comment: imagine `array.filter(.....).map(.....)` ... in the map, you want to do something that involves the "filtered" array ... you can't use `array`

Comment: it is the higher form of abstraction and resusability of a callback.

Comment: Imagine `function foo(acc, m, index, arr) { ... }`, `numbers.reduce(foo)`…

Comment: @deceze another example `function isUnique(x, index, arr) { /* ... */ }` which is then used as `arr.map(/* ... */).filter(isUnique)`

Comment: In FP reduce is called a fold, which has only access to the accumulator and the current value: `foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`. But sometimes you need a more general mechanism to fold a composite value and luckily there are other recursion schemes in FP: `para :: (a -> [a] -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b`. I guess reduce attempts to achieve the same with its two additional parameters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because not every array will be stored in a variable. You can chain calls to map() & other, or after a call to a function that returns an array, in those cases you can access the array by variable name.

```
functionThatReturnsAnArray(...).map((acc, m, index, arr) => {
    // We can only access the array because 
    //it was passed as an argument to the anonymous function
})
```